# Select value where multiple columns

Tags: php, sql, select

I'm not entirely sure how to properly write a select query that will select a value from a table where two particular values are found in the same row.

```
SELECT value FROM table WHERE id=1 AND field=2
```

What's the correct syntax?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp . Remember to add quotes to the values : id='1'

Comment: Have you tried what you have there?

Comment: quotes only required if the field types are strings, and they don't look like strings to me

Comment: Thanks guys and thanks for the link jose, I was missing the quotes.

Comment: this `1`and `2` are integer or string? if integer then syntax is correct. if string then add quotes arround them.

Answer (score -1):

select * from table_name where id=1 and name='any'
add quotes for string value only

Comment: not the downvoter, but `from column_name`? not a good example for a table name as it could confuse new coders. probably better to use `table_name` for clarity.